# Fibonacci sequence and Euclidean algorithm's connection.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $f_1, f_2,\dots,f_i,\dots$ be the Fibonacci sequence with $f_1=f_2=1$. For any $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ with $a<b$, suppose the Euclidean algorithm takes $n$ long divisions to compute $\gcd(a,b)$. If $a\le f_j$, then $n\le j-1$, for $j\ge2$.

I want to prove this problem. But I can't see any connection between Fibonacci and Euclidean algorithm. If anyone can give a hint about first step, it will be very thankful.

My guess is to use induction.

Comment: There is something about this (with detailed proofs) in the book Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H Cormen. You may find something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property is known under the name of Lamé's theorem (http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LamesTheorem.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

The Euclidean algorithm is very efficient whenever a step has a large quotient. If your current pair is $a,b$ and $a=qb+r$ with a large $q$, then your next number $r$ is a lot smaller than $a$.

If, however, all your steps leave a nonzero remainder but a quotient of $q=1$, your progress is as slow as it could possibly be. And this happens exactly when every number is merely the sum of the smaller number and a remainder, meaning...?